# PhantomJS - Permission Denied

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium and PhantomJS with a Python script that I am writing and I am having difficulties starting the PhantomJS service through the script, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asp_scraper.py", line 59, in <module>
    scraper = DanishScraper()
  File "asp_scraper.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='./phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 84, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to GhostDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to GhostDriver
```

This is what I have for my app so far:

```
import re
import string
import urlparse

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class DanishScraper(object):
  def __init__(self):
      self.url = "http://www.realtor.ca/RealtorSearch.aspx"
      self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='./phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')
      self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)



  def scrape(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)

    # Select state selection dropdown
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id('ProvinceIds'))
    option_indexes = range(1, len(select.options))

    for index in option_indexes:
      select.select_by_index(index)
      self.driver.find_element_by_id
    print option_indexes

if __name__ == '__main__':
scraper = DanishScraper()
scraper.scrape()
```

Does it have anything to do with the location of the executable file potentially? I am running on Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan) with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue with similar symptoms on Mac OS. Installing a patched PhantomJS binary downloaded from [here](https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases) helped me to solve the problem.